# How to do file upload with dredd using swagger

Tags: javascript, file-upload, automated-tests, swagger, dredd

This is what I'm passing in my api.description.yml

```
  parameters:
    - name: "file"
      in: "formData"
      required: true
      type: file
      description: fileupload
  consumes:
    - multipart/form-data;
```

Not sure where/how can I send file data in hooks or in the yml file?

Comment: didn't you find any solution?

Comment: I would also be interested in the solution if you found it.

Answer (score 0):

See the [Sending Multipart Requests](https://dredd.org/en/latest/how-to-guides.html#sending-multipart-requests) section in Dredd's docs:

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
title: "Testing 'multipart/form-data' Request API"
version: '1.0'
consumes:
- multipart/form-data; boundary=CUSTOM-BOUNDARY
produces:
- application/json; charset=utf-8
paths:
'/data':
    post:
    parameters:
        - name: text
        in: formData
        type: string
        required: true
        x-example: "test equals to 42"
        - name: json
        in: formData
        type: string
        required: true
        x-example: '{"test": 42}'
    responses:
        200:
        description: 'Test OK'
        examples:
            application/json; charset=utf-8:
            test: 'OK'
```